# Error while Trying To Print the First Occurrence of a repeating Character in a String using Python 3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, printing

I am writing a simple program to replace the repeating characters in a string with an `*(asterisk)`. But the thing here is I can print the 1st occurrence of a repeating character in a string, but not the other occurrences.

For example,
if my **input** is `Google`, my **output** should be `Go**le`.

I am able to replace the characters that repeat with an asterisk, but just cant find a way to print the 1st occurrence of the character. In other words, my output right now is `****le`.

Have a look at my **`Python3`** code for this:

```
s = 'Google'
s = s.lower()
for i in s:
    if s.count(i)>1:
        s = s.replace(i,'*')
print(s)
```

Can someone suggest me what should be done to get the required output?

Comment: Well currently you're replacing everything with a count greater than 1. What you need to do instead is keep a running count of each letter and once it is greater than 1, replace it with an asterisk. A dictionary would work well for that. Not that strings are immutable, so every time you remove/change an element you're creating a new list. IOW building this new string from scratch would actually be faster.

Comment: @PM2Ring No.... my program considers characters as case insensitive, That's why, in the 2nd line of my code, I have converted all characters in the string into lowercase

Comment: @PM2Ring LOL, this is not homework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` will replace ALL occurences of the char. You need to follow on the characters you already have seen, and if they are repeated to replace JUST this character (at specific index).

Strings don't support index assignment, so we can build a new list that represents the new string and `''.join()` it afterwards.

Using `Set` you can follow on what items you have seen already.

It would look like this:

```
s = 'Google'
seen = set()
new_string = []

for c in s:
    if c.lower() in seen:
        new_string.append('*')
    else:
        new_string.append(c)
        seen.add(c.lower())

new_string = ''.join(new_string)
print(new_string)
Go**le
```

Comment: @Vinny This one works, in a way that, when I gave **`print(new_string)`** , it gave **`['g', 'o', '*', '*', 'l', 'e']`** . But the desired output is `Go**le`

Comment: @PM2Ring you're right. I've updated the solution to provide that

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ new_string is a list, you will need to `join()` it first so it become a string. I updated the code so `new_string` will print the expected string now

Comment: I just noticed and figured it out, it is a better way indeed

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ check out the new answer. It is better because I removed the unnecessary `zip`

Comment: @Vinny Yeah Great!

Comment: Try to do it without calling `.lower` twice on each char.

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach:

First, you need to find the nth occurrence of the character. Then, you can replace other occurrences by using this snippet:

```
s = s[:position] + '*' + s[position+1:]
```

Full example code:

```
def find_nth(haystack, needle, n):
    start = haystack.find(needle)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start+len(needle))
        n -= 1
    return start

s = 'Google'
s_lower = s.lower()

for c in s_lower:
    if s_lower.count(c) > 1:
        position = find_nth(s_lower, c, 2)
        s = s[:position] + '*' + s[position+1:]
print(s)
```

Runnable link: https://repl.it/Mc4U/4

---

Regex approach:

```
import re

s = 'Google'

s_lower = s.lower()

for c in s_lower:
    if s_lower.count(c) > 1:
        position = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(c, s_lower)][1]
        s = s[:position] + '*' + s[position+1:]

print(s)
```

Runnable link: https://repl.it/Mc4U/3

Answer (score 2):

How about using list comprensions? When constructing a list from another list (which is kind of what you are doing here, since we're considering strings as lists), list comprehension is a great tool:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

inputstring = 'Google'.lower()
outputstring = ''.join(
    [char if inputstring.find(char, 0, index) == -1 else '*'
    for index, char in enumerate(inputstring)])
print(outputstring)
```

This results in `go**le`.

Hope this helps!

(**edited** to use '*' as the replacement character instead of '#')

Comment: it's scanning from the beginning *until* the current index, not *from* the current index. Granted, I wasn't thinking of performance, but I'm guessing this uses less memory than adding a lookup set and I also think it's more efficient than regular expressions. These are unfounded claims however. :-)